# Unable to save screenshot in gallery

Tags: android

I,m trying to capture a snapshot of an android activity, but unable to save it in gallery.
the screenshot turns black
I'm also trying to convert this snapshot into a pdf file..Plz help..
This is my code..

```
 public static void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, bytes);
          File f = new File("sdcard/camera_app/test.png");
          //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.png");
          try {
              f.createNewFile();
              FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);

              fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
              fo.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
```

Comment: try fo.flush() before close

Comment: AND also how do I convert the same,into pdf file??

Comment: u can try pdfWriter Api

Comment: Before saving like this make one directory and save Images in that directory .

Comment: first things first, do you have permissions to write files to disk ?

Comment: Do you mean the manifest file?? yes I did enter the code..

Comment: Every things fine,but the screenshot is turning black,once I open it....and also it is not showing up in the gallery...Plz hlp!!

Comment: `f.createNewFile();`. Remove that. Statement makes no sense. The file will be created by the new FileOutputStream.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes`. Please do not name that `bytes`. Better: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos`.

Comment: What is the size of the file that you find afterwards?

Comment: `but unable to save it in gallery.`. But you are not trying that. You are saving to the file system.

Comment: the file size after I save it is 49.08KB..How do I make it go to the gallery..I am very new to Android..So srry for these silly qsntns...

Answer (score 0):

To register an image into the gallery:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```